# For which odd positive integer $n$, is it true that $−1$ is not a positive power of $2$ modulo $n$? [request for more extensive results]

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, divisibility

> For which odd positive integer $n$, is it true that $−1$ is not a positive power of $2$ modulo $n$ i.e. $[−1]\ne [2^k],\forall k>0$ in $\mathbf{Z}_n$ ?

This question was asked in [For which odd positive integer $n$ , is it true that $-1$ is not a positive power of $2$ modulo $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837903/for-which-odd-positive-integer-n-is-it-true-that-1-is-not-a-positive-powe)

There, the following sequence was referenced: https://oeis.org/A091317

However, the sequences given only cover $n$ prime.  What if $n$ is not prime?

This is not completely trivial, as $n=15$ does not have $-1$ as a positive power modulo $n$, even though $n=3$ and $n=5$ do.  That is, $3$ divides $2^n + 1$ for some $n$, and $5$ divides $2^n + 1$ for some $n$, but $15$ does not divide $2^n + 1$ for some $n$.  At the same time, $33$ does divide $2^n + 1$ for some $n$ (as do $3$ and $11$, obviously).

Is there a way to apply this sequence to composites and prime powers?

Comment: These are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A014657 My comment at the earlier question, about the llikelihood of a useful characterization, still holds.

Comment: Thank you for an answer to the non-prime case.  The original question only had the link to the prime case.

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." @Arturo, that's exactly what Edwin did. This question should not have been closed. I have reopened it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I was not aware my vote would close it by itself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: But in any case, they should not have **identical** titles (up to the extra space before the punctuation!) This title should indicate this is a re-ask or a request for expansion.

Comment: @Arturo, right, I'll edit the title. The question has the group-theory tag, and you have a group-theory gold badge, so one vote from you is all it takes to close (and one vote from me is all it took to reopen, since it has the number-theory tag, and I have a number-theory gold badge).

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in my comment, the sequence is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A014657
It seems unlikely to me that anyone can say very much that's useful about those values of $n$.